# Is this a dual cap?

Tags: capacitor, dual

As you can see below [image], this cap is marked 8 + 8 uf. Does this indicate that it is a dual cap? There only seem to be two actual terminals, as you can see here [image], although there are also three lugs around the rim. Can anyone help me understand what this component is and what the terminals are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a dual capacitor. One of the terminals is common between the two capacitors in the package. The case acts as the third terminal, but you will need to see the capacitor datasheet to find out which terminals are connected to which capacitors.

Comment: Great, thanks - I probably should have started with a more basic question i.e. what exactly is a dual capacitor? Just two caps in one package? Does that mean the two terminals on the base are + of cap 1 and + of cap 2, and the case is - of both?

Comment: @DarkAges: You would have to see the datasheet for the capacitor; I don't believe that there is a fixed standard for this.

Comment: Hmmm, easier said than done - I think the cap is about 45 years old. With the holder off I can read more of the print on the can - it says BEAM - ECHO - CCL / 8 + 8 uF / 350 V DC WKG / RED OUTER / CAN NEG / EL 624 D8 / BRITISH MADE. I have Googled for a datasheet but no joy - does the print itself hold any more information?

Comment: Sorry have just seen edited answer - obviously the print on the can tells me that the can is the negative terminal for both caps - is it as simple as that i.e. can I assume there is nothing in there except two caps?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like there are two concentric caps in there, with the black connected to the inside one.